# Header content get small and hide when minimized

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make one header in HTML with the help of CSS but the problem which I am facing is that whenever I minimize (restore down) my browser, what happen is that the header line which is **HOME** is get hide between those link and the link which I have specified with some hover effect got little bit downwards. Is there any solution by which even if I minimize my browser as much as I can the header position must be fixed and the content of that header must look as same as it was at normal stage.

Images are as follows: [image: This is the problem i am facing]

Code :

```
<body>

    <div id='header'>

        <center><h1>Home</h1></center>

    </div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">spam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">eggs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS file you can find it on FIDDLE** : [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shashank_15/G3T6J/)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this Sharma: http://jsfiddle.net/G3T6J/4/

Comment: Your header has a percentage height. Set it to a fixed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `position:fixed` from `#header` and `#nav`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3T6J/3/)

Comment: I think he needs menu has position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work i think:

**html**

```
<body>
<div id="menuCont">
    <div id='header'>

        <center><h1>Home</h1></center>

</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">spam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">eggs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div> 
    <div id="footer">

</div>

</body>
```

**css**

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;

}
li
{
float:left;
width: 25%;

}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;

width:100%;

color:#404040;


text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
/* background-color:#E0E0E0; */


background-color: #323B50;
color: #FFFFFF;

-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
border-radius: 1px;

}
#nav {
        background:#FFFFFF;
        color:#000000;
        opacity:1; 




        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        font-family:'Ubuntu';
        border-radius: 1px;
        position: relative;
        top: 8%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        left: 0%;
        height: 3.5%;
        padding: 0%;
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    #header
    {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 100%;
        height:8%;
        color: #FFFFFF; 
        background: #323B50;
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        font-family:'Ubuntu';
        border-radius: 1px;

        top: 0;

        z-index: 100;
        left:0%;
    }
    #footer 
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top:216%;
        left: 0;
        height:3%;
        color: #FFFFFF; 
        background: #323B50;
        width: 100%
    }

#menuCont{
   position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3T6J/6/)